# How do I fix Input/Output error during Lubuntu installation?

Tags: installation, lubuntu

I tried to install Lubuntu on my PC (Pentium 4160 GB Hard disk, 1256 MB Ram). I have downloaded ISO image file from torrent which is on Lubuntu site, then burnt CD at
32x speed and tried to install on my PC.

Installation wizard successfully loaded. When it started to copy file from CD to hard drive after 2-3 minutes, it is showing a dialog-box with READ INPUT / OUTPUT ERROR.

It is indicating damaged CD or the CD is not burnt at proper speed.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. You have other method to install ubuntu/lubuntu on your machine. Check this [post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/185687/ubuntu-doesnt-start-from-usb-after-installation/192199#192199)

Comment: Please try burning the CD at a slower speed, as it asks to do. Also, check the CD for errors by pressing any key when you see a man and a keyboard during the boot cycle, and using arrow keys to select language, keymap, and the option to check the disk.

Comment: Can I use nero for burn image..?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install)

Answer (score 1):

Usually when downloading an iso image for Ubuntu I use a torrent because it is checked during and after download to make sure it's all there, then I will burn the iso image at the slowest speed to make the disc stable and longer lasting (burning too fast can cause errors)...

Answer (score 0):

a few possibilities:

1. check your hard disc https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools#Testing_a_Drive
2. check your CPU with http://systester.sourceforge.net/downloads.php
3. check your burnt CD with "Check disk for errors" on the LiveCD boot menu
4. Check your ram with "Test Memory" on the LiveCD boot menu

if none of the above works, it's probably a bad cable

Answer (score 0):

May be this is happening because Lubuntu ISO wasn't burnt on CD perfectly. Why you are trying with the harder way? Just install Lubuntu on a USB disk using Unetbootin. You can find this software here http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Then boot your PC with the USB disk and install Lubuntu as the same process as CD installation.

Let us know if you face any further problem. Good luck.